# UTC time stamp needs to be saved in java variable

Tags: timestamp, utc

In response from SMTP2GO after successful email sending the response is in form URL Encoded having the time element as `time=2018-08-30T09%3A22%3A31Z`.
I need the time to be saved in java variable as 2018-08-30 09:22
How can i do that ; any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

Comment: Thanks @TomBombadil but i already have the time i need to convert it to readable format.

Comment: I'd do it with string manipulation but its probably not the easiest way.

Comment: In which type do you have the time? Is it a string?

Comment: it is coming in form encoded through form param i am taking it as a String.

Comment: Posted a string manipulation answer. Sorry if it does not help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm");
    String urlParam = "time=2018-08-30T09%3A22%3A31Z";
    String[] splitParam = urlParam.split("=");
    if (splitParam.length == 2 && splitParam[0].equals("time")) {
        String incomingTimeString = URLDecoder.decode(splitParam[1], StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.parse(incomingTimeString);
        String timeStringForDisplay = time.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(timeStringForDisplay);
    }
```

The output from the above snippet is the desired:

> 2018-08-30 09:22

Notice that the time is in UTC. You may want to convert it to your user’s time zone or at least print the offset with the time.

The pretty way to do it is to use `URLDecoder` for decoding `%3A` from the encoded string into colons and to use a proper date-time class for holding the date and time, like `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant` (the `Timestamp` class proposed in a comment would be a poor choice; it’s long outdated and was only designed for storing and retrieving timestamp values to and from SQL databases). Your time string is in ISO 8601 format, the format that `OffsetDateTime`, `Instant` and other modern date-time classes parse as their default. This means that we don’t have to specify the format.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

If time is a String you could do:

```
String[] timeparts = time.split("T");
String[] timeparts2 = timeparts[1].split("%3A");

String result = timeparts[0] + " " + timeparts2[0] + ":" + timeparts2[1];
```

However, this is not a pretty way to do it.